# <div> not created on fly within javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I'm using the following JavaScript function create a `<div>` element on the fly.

```js
function display()
{
    if (accessTokenValue === '')
    {
        alert("inside if");

        $('#mainDivId').addClass('ui-content jqm-content feed');
        $('<div id="linkToInstagramDivId"></div>')
            .html('
<p><img src="img/instagram-logotype.png" alt="" /></p>
<p>Link To Instagram</p>
<div><input type="button" data-inline="true"
value="Sign In" onclick="LinkToInstagram();"></div>'
            )
            .appendTo('#mainDivId');

        alert("inside after if");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("inside else");

        $('#mainDivId').addClass('ui-content jqm-content');
        $('<div id="uploadToInstagramDivId"></div>')
            .html('
<p>Upload Photos To Instagram</p>
<input type="button" value="Upload Photos" data-inline="true"
onclick="UploadToInstagram();">'
            )
            .appendTo("#mainDivId");
    }
}
```

No change happens to the page, it remains blank. Also, Firebug shows nothing on creation of the above html content.

Comment: i think you missed adding the div to the document as we do in dom. can you check the same with jquery

Comment: how to do with jquery?????

Comment: are the alerts firing?

Comment: yes the alerts are firing, even the class is not getting add up to that div #mainDivId i checked it out in firebug

Comment: please show us html, or please produce the codes at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: i am not a jquery expert but that is the same think we do in js after creating a new element we finally add it to the document. you can check it on SO also

Comment: No escape character '\' is needed.

Comment: someone edited it and have put escape sequences not me

Comment: I did reject the edit but it went through anyway, don't agree if people are formatting code while changing it's meaning.

Comment: check out the link 
http://jsfiddle.net/FTFum/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var temp=$('<div id="linkToInstagramDivId"></div>');
temp.html('<p><img src="img/instagram-logotype.png" alt="" /></p><p>Link To Instagram</p><div><input type="button" data-inline="true" value="Sign In" onclick="LinkToInstagram();"></div>');

$('#mainDivId').after(temp);
```

**Make sure you have added latest jquery.js** .

**Edit:** The problem is you are loading display function when your page is not loaded that's why it did not show changes. Write your complete display function and function call in ready() like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var accessTokenValue="";
    function display()
    {
        if (accessTokenValue == '')
        {
            alert("inside if");

            $('#mainDivId').addClass('ui-content jqm-content feed');
            $('<div id="linkToInstagramDivId"></div>')
                .html('<p><img src="img/instagram-logotype.png" alt="" /></p><p>Link To Instagram</p><div><input type="button" data-inline="true" value="Sign In" onclick="LinkToInstagram();"></div>')
                .appendTo('#mainDivId');
            alert("inside after if");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("inside else");

            $('#mainDivId').addClass('ui-content jqm-content');
            $('<div id="uploadToInstagramDivId"></div>')
                .html('<p>Upload Photos To Instagram</p><input type="button" value="Upload Photos" data-inline="true" onclick="UploadToInstagram();">')
                .appendTo("#mainDivId");
        }
    }
    display();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

its working fine for me there though

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$(document).ready (function () {
var accessTokenValue = "Terminator";

function display () {
 if (accessTokenValue == '') {
    alert("inside if");

      $('#mainDivId').addClass('ui-content jqm-content feed');
        $('<div id="linkToInstagramDivId"></div>')
            .html('<p><img src="img/instagram-logotype.png" alt="" /></p><p>Link To Instagram</p><div><input type="button" data-inline="true" value="Sign In" onclick="LinkToInstagram();"></div>')
           .appendTo('#mainDivId');

       alert("inside after if");
    } else {
        alert("inside else");

    $('#mainDivId').addClass('ui-content jqm-content');
    $('<div id="uploadToInstagramDivId"></div>')
        .html('<p>Upload Photos To Instagram</p>
            <input type="button" value="Upload Photos" data-inline="true"
            onclick="UploadToInstagram();">').appendTo("#mainDivId");
 }

 //call display onLoad
 display ();

});
```

**LIVE DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/k9pCY/1/

just see through that you have loaded all Jquery lib properly or not and remove those nackward slashes from your code, they arent necessary :)

Happy Coding :)

Comment: @user3519216: you mean the jsfiddle, which i have posted didnt work ? or your code is not working ?

Comment: @user3519216: it doesnt matter from where u call the function, what  i  did in jsfiddle was just an example to show the working code. when exactly are you thinking to call that function ?

Comment: when page gets load the function should exexcute automatically like calling within script...

Comment: @user3519216:that should not be a problem, you just call the complete function inside `$(document).ready(function () { //call display() here })`. edited my answer aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Without Jquery...

```
function display(){
if (accessTokenValue === '') {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.id = "linkToInstagramDivId";
newdiv.innerHTML = '<p><img src="img/instagram-logotype.png" alt="" /></p><p>Link To Instagram</p><div><input type="button" data-inline="true" value="Sign In" onclick="LinkToInstagram();"></div>';
document.getElementById("mainDivId").appendChild(newdiv);
} else {
var maindiv = document.getElementById('mainDivId');
maindiv.className += " ui-content jqm-content";
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.innerHTML = '<p>Upload Photos To Instagram</p><input type="button" value="Upload Photos" data-inline="true" onclick="UploadToInstagram();">';
maindiv.appendChild(newdiv);
};
```

};

Forgot a semicolon... oops :)